# How to handler an DocumentSnapshot in Koltin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I Have an Firestore ArrayList response and it comes in DocumentSnapshot. I would like to know how i can get every `animeId` filtered by document.
Heres is the Firestore DB:

[image]

Here's the code to get the Firestore Data:

```
val animeRef = firestoreClient.collection("Users")
        animeRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { documents ->
            if (documents.isSuccessful) {
                val name = mutableListOf<String>()
                for (document in documents.result) {
                    val animeId = document.toString()
                    name.add(animeId)
                }
                println(name)
            }
        }
```

Executing this code I have this response:

[image]

[image]

How can I  get the `animeId` filtered by the `key`?

Comment: What do y ou mean by "get every animeId filtered by document"? What is the expected result?

Comment: That I alredy solved, but now I need to know how i can get list of value. I just want the list of 'animeId', but, when i do the "addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                animeIdList = document.data!!
            }" the result is "{animeId=[1, 2, 3, 4]}". I need to get the array [1, 2, 3, 4] and use the values, like animeId[0] = 1, animeId[1] = 2 and etc but when i do animeId[0] the result is "[1, 2, 3, 4]"

Comment: [This will help you](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot)